# ImageMagick PNG to PDF of given dimensions

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, png

I created a cover for a book in GIMP, exported to a PNG, and now need to convert to a PDF. I know how to do this with ImageMagick, but the final PDF has to have specific dimensions for printing. How can I specify PDF dimensions?
If it's of any use, the PNG image's dimensions are `4149px x 1836px`, and the PDF should be `1383pt x 612pt`.

Comment: @KJ Could you provide an example command?

Answer (score 0):

`convert cover.png -units PixelsPerInch -density 216x216 cover.pdf`
Density is calculated by converting point measurement to inches, and dividing pixel dimensions by inch dimensions.